# Is there a more modern, OO version of "Let's Build a Compiler"?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, oop, refactoring, recursion

Is there a more modern, maybe object-oriented, equivalent to Jack Crenshaw's "[Let's Build a Compiler](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/)" series?

A while back I stumbled across "[Let's Build a Compiler](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/)" and could just not resist writing some code.  I wrote a recursive-descent C compiler in C# that output .NET CIL.  "Write once, leak everywhere" was my slogan.

Too bad I did not realize until too late that parsing C is a nightmare.

I am now interested in writing a Java compiler in Java that outputs .NET CIL or assemblies with the goal of being self-bootstrapping.  I was hoping there might some newer tutorials kicking around.

As an aside, would you spend more time with up-front design or would you just write a ton of tests to support the ability to mercilessly refactor.  Thinking back, I am leaning towards the latter.  The compiler worked but the code was really awful.

Comment: I recommend you try using parser combinators. It has been an enlightening experience for me. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator

Comment: For those who are not familiar with it Crenshaw's tutorial does nearly no theory, but concentrates an showing how to bash out a working compiler in a minimum of code. The surprising thing about it is how *much* one can learn about compilers in general from it. SO, Justin isn't asking for just any compiler reference but for a very specific thing. I don't know of one.

Comment: @dmckee - Exactly right.  You understand my question completely. @ChaosPandion - Thanks.  Parser combinators are one of the things I plan to play with in Scala.  I want this to be in vanilla Java though.

Comment: Is the question about a compiler FOR an oo language, or writing a compiler IN a more oo-way?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi - The question is about writing a compiler in a more oo-way.  In this case, I will also be writing a compiler for an OO language (Java).  It sounds like I am just going to have to write the tutorial myself.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you completely missed the point of Crenshaw's tutorials. LBC isn't about writing pretty, clean, or efficient code. It's all about bringing something that's steeped in formal theory down to a level where the casual coder can easily and rapidly hack out a rudimentary (but working!) compiler.

When I read through LBC years back, I rewrote the examples in C#. I'm sure the class layout isn't the best, or tasks segregated properly, but it's comparable to his Pascal. I'd be happy to share the code with you if you like-- let me know and I can post it online and share the link.

In my spare time I've been hacking out some writing with the aim of unifying the philosophies of LBC and Basics of Compiler Design together-- walkling away with practical, working code at the end of each unit/chapter, with also discuss some theoretical stuff after exploring the ideas so the reader understands why things are the way they are. But it took Crenshaw years to write his incomplete series, so mine my be a pipe dream... and I use C (exactly because it's not C++ or Java).

Comment: Sorry you feel I missed the point.  As you read in my question, I wrote a C compiler in C# using Crenshaw's tutorial.  The result also resembled his Pascal. This was ok because I wanted to rewrite it in C but it makes little sense for C#.  It should be possible to write a similarly practical tutorial to "rapidly hack out" a compiler in an OO way that is similar in spirit to Crenshaw but more modern.  My question is if there was one.  If you do not write yours first, I may write it myself.  I have some ideas.

Comment: Hey @Justin, If you wrote something, can you show it to us?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Terence Parr's "Language Implementation Patterns"](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns). He wrote ANTLR - a parser generator for Java - so knows his stuff. It explains the principles of compiler design really well and builds up gradually.

[Martin Fowler's "Domain Specific Languages"](http://martinfowler.com/dsl.html) is also good. It has a slightly different agenda than being a pure compilers course, but is a good reference on the key concepts of language design.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of ["MiniJava"](http://www.cambridge.org/us/features/052182060X/) and associated work based on the "Modern Compiler Implementation in Java" family of books. This doesn't quite meet all the requirements you mention as a MiniJava implementation will, generally, generate native code - but the backend can easily be changed to emit MSIL or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently built a compiler at my company using [BNFC](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/), at first I was instructed to use Flex and Bison (C/C++) but I found them to be a pain so I used BNFC to generate the Flex and Bison files.

Can't say I liked the code, my grammar was pretty big and so was the generated visitor but nothing I couldn't handle, I TDDed from the beginning so I always had enough tests to refactor and but I also kept a UML diagram to help me think about the additional classes I wrote.

There actually is a book called [Implementing Programming Languages](http://www1.digitalgrammars.com/ipl-book/) self described as "a self-study book, and to some extent, a manual to the BNFC tool" had I read it I would probably have struggled less with implementation decisions but overall I found BNFC to be intuitive enough to be able to use it by only reading the [manual](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/LBNF-report.pdf) and the [tutorial](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/tutorial.html)

Last but not least, it can also be used with other languages including Java (with Cup and JLex)

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at the [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) project? It is a Python implementation of the Python language. Maybe it can provide some inspiration for your goal of self-bootstrapping Java?

Answer (score 2):

What about [Writing Compilers and Interpreters: A Software Engineering Approach by Ronald Mak](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470177071)?

Answer (score 1):

When thinking of learning this stuff, you should have a look at book [language-implementation-patterns](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) and [antlr-reference](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference)

Answer (score 1):

If you like to learn by example, the code for [Finch](http://finch.stuffwithstuff.com/), a little programming language of mine:

1. Is written in object-oriented C++.
2. Is very clean.
3. Includes a bytecode compiler.

Answer (score 1):

How about Watt & Brown's Programming Language Processors in Java. It demonstrates what OO patterns to use in (simple) compiler design. I used it with C# successfully.